# Mac Pro how to boot in safe mode with a Windows Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, mac-pro

Model No: A1186
Mac Pro 3,2

I think it's a 2008 with an unknown version of MacOSX installed.

I'm stuck at the blue screen, I'm pretty sure it's a permissions problem, as I lost the network connection when setting it up.  But I can't boot into safe mode.  I just bought it online.  I also tried to boot a Clonezilla Live CD with little luck.

Comment: as you don't know what OS is on it, a few things to try. Shift boots to safe mode. Cmd/r will boot to recovery mode [should be Windows key for Cmd] if it has Lion or later. Alt key will boot to show available bootable drives attached, if any. The DVD drive on a machine that old might not be in the best condition, so consider a USB key to boot from.

Comment: I actually got it to boot last night, it didn't like the keyboard I had hooked up.  Sorry for the non-question.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working. Look into getting an SSD in that, in the optical bay using the 'spare' SATA under where the CPU fans are. Gave mine a new lease of life :) [should be 3,1 btw, an Early 08]

Comment: Yeah it is a 3,1

Comment: Cool. Then an SSD as boot drive will really give it some zip, even at 3GB/s rather than 6 in a new machine. I use iTunes' launch time as a test. Used to be best part of a minute, now 4 seconds.